# C++ boost::get and visitor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, boost

I've made a vector with a `boost::variant` of multiple types like this:

```
std::vector<boost::variant<type1,type2,type3,...and so on>>
```

And after that, I've made a `typedef` to rename this whole type as `vecTypesVar` and the variant named `typesVar`

```
typedef boost::variant<type1,type2,type3,...and so on> typesVar
typedef std::vector<typesVar> vecTypesVar
```

Now I've made a for-loop on that vector to and using the options `.which` I'm trying to make an implementation for each type like this.

```
vecTypesVar type = getTypesData();
for (auto i = 0; i < type.size(); ++i)
{
    switch (type[i].which())
    {
    case 0:
        break;

    case 1:
        break;

    case 2:
        break;
    default: ;
    }
}
```

So, here it's started the problem, on each **case** of the **switch** I'm trying to make a variable the same type as the one that came.

For example:

```
case 0:
    auto data = boost::get<type1>(type[i]);
```

but I'm getting an error which said:

> error C2248: 'type1::type1' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'type1'

I've also tried to use visitors like this:
template

```
class port_visitator : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
    T operator()(typesVar type) const
    {
        return boost::get<T>(type);
    }
};
```

and used that in my switch:

```
case 0:
   auto data = apply_visitor(port_visitator<type1>(), type[i]);
```

But I'm receiving the same error:

> error C2248: 'type1::type1' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class 'type1'

**EDIT:**
Here is the type1 constructor:

```
template<typename T, dataType ST>
class type1: public sometype<T, ST>, public othertype<T, ST>, public anothertype
{
public:
    template <typename T1>
    type1(
        CSimSwcBase*           _plgInstance,
        const char*            _name,
        const T1&              _initialValue,
        const long             _version,
        const SimFunc_t        _eventFunc           = NULL,
        void*                  _eventFuncInstance   = NULL,
        const long             _size                = GetSize<T>::SIZE,
        const unsigned long    _portMode            = 0,
        const bool             _definedDefaultValue = false,
        void*                  _pDefaultValue       = NULL,
        const unsigned long    _defaultValueSize    = 0,
        const bool             _bBuffered           = false)
        : sometype(_plgInstance, _name, _initialValue, _size, _portMode, _eventFunc, _eventFuncInstance, _definedDefaultValue, _pDefaultValue, _defaultValueSize, _bBuffered)
        , othertype(dynamic_cast<sometype*>(this))
        , m_bUseSyncRef (false)
        , m_bGetDefaultValues(false)
        , m_bReportError(true)
        , m_errorCount(0)
        , m_maxError(100)
        , m_bDoOnlyStartupTest(false)
        , m_bStartupTestPassed(false)
        , m_bNotConnectedReported(false)
    {
        setupVersion(_version);
    }
}
```

Is anyone of you how knows how can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of clear enough need to actually construct and copy here:

```
auto data = boost::get<type1>(type[i]);
```

you could simply make due with a reference like this:

```
auto& data = boost::get<type1>(type[i]);
```

Thus eliminating the need to construct altogether.

Comment: It can't be, I just check and the constructor it's put as public like this.  `class type1: public sometype<T, ST>, public othertype<T, ST>, public otherothertype`     and also    `public:
    template <typename T1>
    type1(...){....}`

Comment: @Vali this code here in your comment is not the constructors -- it is the declaration of inheritance.

Comment: @Vali OK checking it

Comment: @Vali OK do you have the copy constructor or operator= being either `private` or `=delete`ed?

Comment: @Vali Interesting -- does this compile? `auto& data = boost::get<type1>(type[i]);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178611/discussion-between-skepticalempiricist-and-vali).

Comment: I just wanna let you know that you were right, now it's working perfectly fine :D, just edit your answer with the real one to be able to vote your answer as a correct one :), thx

Comment: Ok sure, glad I could help : )

Comment: @Vali The answer is now up to date to reflect the progress we've made. Let me know if you think there's anything further to edit.

Comment: if do you want and have some time could you help me also with this weird [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005067/c-can-not-pass-object-by-constructor)?